# Flask-Migrate not creating migrations

Tags: python, flask

I have a app_db module in my application

```
import os 
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from app.models.models import *

    if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') is None:
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://ewojitxcrklhxpq:wkAO8d-hdr2hGoQXYadbjMKhGR@ec2-23-23-214-211.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d7i8ucmlletq2mmv'
    else:
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']


    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    manager = Manager(app)
    manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


    if(__name__=='main'):
       manager.run()
```

all my model classes are in `app.models.models`. My application connects to the DB and returns results correctly by when i run `python app_db.py db init` no migration is created ? What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create an automatic migration script, then the most likely reason for Alembic not detecting any changes is that the changes are already in the database, so there is no difference between your models and the database schema. Try deleting all the tables in your database with `db.drop_all()`, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

To allow flask-migrate recognise your models, ensure that you import your models in your env.py file. I imported it immediately after all imports and it worked.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use `Alembic` for Schema Migration, its created by the author of `SQLAlchemy` itself, Its best for the Migrations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Flask-Migrate is an Alembic wrapper.